# Intel 6200 Wifi - cant enable

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, wifi-driver

I purchased 2 Intel 6200 advanced-N AGN wifi cards to replace the stock card in my HP pavilion g6 2299ea, simply for the 5GHz capability. I thought it would be a straight swap, install drivers and carry on abut my day but it has cost me an all-nighter and roughly 10-12 fresh installs of different Windows.

Here's what I did so far:

- On Windows 10, Swapped the cards, installed the Intel driver for Win 8.1 but wifi would not turn on.
- Tried different drivers.
- Tried the other card but same issue so they cant be faulty
- Tried on fresh install of Windows 7, worked after I installed the windows 7 driver
- Tried on fresh install of Windows 10, same issue
- Since the latest driver was for Windows 8.1 I tried that, didn't work
- Installed another fresh 8.1 and it worked! Did my updates and rebooted, broken again
- Painfully, I deleted all the updates one by one, rebooted, still broken - Reset network by cmd

In device manager, it always says 'This device is working properly' but always has a red X on the wifi signal bar and never allows me to turn the wifi on. Ideally, I'd like to remain on win 10.

Comment: It sounds to me, based on the information you provide,the card only supports Windows 7 and Windows 8.1

Comment: That's what I thought but even on 7 and 8.1 its hit or miss. In fact, since I posted I have gotten it to work on win10 by hotswapping the card but once again, fails after reboot. Hotswapping doesn't work every time either

Comment: Honestly, In my personal extensive experience, every single device that has used any sort of Intel wireless card, has experienced stability problems.  *I wouldn't use Intel wireless adapter if you paid me to use it.* You likely would have better luck with a string and two cans.

Comment: Checking other forums, the intel cards dont seem to be highly liked. Probably for the reasons you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is too obvious, but just in case... Have you checked if your wifi is not disabled? Sometimes there is a hardware switch that is turned off. Sometimes is a key combination.

Other than that, on intel's site there isn't actually a driver specifically for windows 10, so you seem out of luck:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/59470/Intel-Centrino-Advanced-N-6200-Dual-Band

Also on this table there's a lot of info on driver versions and wireless adapters, and yours is listed as not supported:
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000006024.html

But since on device manager your card is listed as 'working properly', maybe these procedures might help:

- Go to Control Panel, then Network and Internet, then Network and Sharing Centre, then click on the left on "Change Adapter Settings". Right click "Wireless Network Connection" to enable it again.

Another attempt:

- Open Control Panel in your laptop.
- Hardware and Sound, Device Manager
- Click on Network Adapters List, select your network adapter
- Right Click and Select Properties
- Click on Power Management tab
- uncheck Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power option.
- click on OK.

UPDATE:
I found another attempt someone with the same scenario tried and for that case it worked.

Source:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/intel-advanced-n-6200-abg-not-working-with-windows/4dc37f1b-2614-4bc7-9f80-6104464ebe19

Steps:
- Get Intel Driver 15.17.0.1 -> It is inside the 18.12.1 version here (https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25223/Wireless-Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-and-Drivers-for-Windows-7-). Direct link for download: (http://downloadmirror.intel.com/25158/eng/Wireless_18.12.1_%20Win32.exe)

- Right-click on the setup file of the driver and select Properties.
- Select Compatibility tab.
- Check Run this program in Compatibility mode.
- Let the driver install and then check the functionality.

Comment: Thanks, i tried all of those before anything else. It usually is the simplest things isnt it? I dont think it is this time however :(

Comment: Hmmm sorry to hear that :/ Hey, have you tried reaching out for Intel? Won't hurt to try and send them an email!

Comment: I updated the answer with another attempt you may try

Comment: The card has been working okay for the last day. I didnt do anything special, just reinstalled win10 and didnt do any drivers. It does encounter that problem randomly but disable/enable in device manager seems to fix it this time. Tried your new method anyway and its the same driver version that windows update did for me. So weird that it just 'decided' to work. Lets see how it holds up ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back the recent Windows 10 update.

My wireless had been working fine for sometime but quit just a week or so after latest major Microsoft Windows 10 update; none of the common suggested solutions on out on the internet at present work.

Answer (score -1):

here is the solution for the wifi not working after upgrading to win 10.....
i've searched for days for a solution and i also buy another pcie wifi module that didn't solve my problem so i had continue my research and i finally found the solution.
At first the solution was looking awkward and so easy to do that i didn't even tried it and ordered a new module win 10 compatible but still no luck so for all of you that think there is no way to make it work don't be stupid as i had been and try it .
This will not cost you any additional money -  just remove your old module and put a scotch tape on the pin 20 of your module and voila! wifi's back and fast and no more orange light...blue light is back. the story behind all this is in windows 7 the wifi switch is activated via proprietary software - from hp in my case that was designed for win 7 maximum no more upgrade available above this version and after upgrading to win 10 the switch is turned off and no possible way to turn it on unless you downgrade to win 7 which is a nonsense so in putting a tape on the pin 20 of the module you bypass the switch and telling the module that it is on and always stay on.

I have included a picture of the module with an arrow showing you where to put the tape .
there is a youtube link that show how to mask the pin. for pcie card it is pin 20 but for other form factor it could be something else like the one in the video it up to you to find the pin that work for you but the secret is to bypass the switch so look at the attach picture and hope you will succeed as i have !

[image: pin20.jpg]

[how to bypass switch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSOqPdBcYcw)

my computer= hp probook 6550b with n6200 ultimate centrino wifi card

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for taking the time to answer. Adding formatting to your answer would make it easier to read, perhaps you could [edit] it and do so.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for my english but it will be easy to handle the problem. No need pin bypass there is an easyer solution.
Just install latest driver I know its for windows 8 but you can install it under windows 10 too. Don't panic!
Windows hardware manager will show you error that device couldn't start.
Just run command:
services.msc
(if you dont know how, just click on Windows left bottom icon and start typing it)
Find WWAN - its like one of the last in the list and change it from manual start to automatic. Restarta your computer.
Thats all folks. Enjoy your wifi signal!